# Indexed properties with Linq?

Tags: c#, indexing, linq-to-objects

In a database we create indexes on columns that we want to query with joins.
Does Linq to objects facilitate this in any way?

I imagine that search performance could be (much) improved when somehow List's can be supported by binary trees (indexes) in memory that are mapped to specific properties of T.

I am thinking of Lists that do not have to be optimized for inserts or deletes.
One could turn off the index for another optimization.

Comment: If you need this kind of functionality. Why not put the data into a list that *is* optimized for searching in the first place?

Comment: "optimized for searching" - how? Note that I am thinking of different search operations not only one property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; LINQ does not use indexes.

Instead, you can use [i4o](http://i4o.codeplex.com/), which does.

Note that many LINQ operations, such as `Distinct`, `Join`, `GroupBy`, and others, will build a hasttable (or hashset, as appropriate) to avoid O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance.
For more information, see Jon Skeet's [EduLINQ series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx).

Comment: i4o: "often over one thousand times faster" - looks promising!